# How to get coordinates (lat/lon) of visible map extent?

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

How to get coordinates (lat/lon) of visible map extent corners for ArcGIS MapView using android SDK?

Comment: Have you tried getExtent()? And convert the 4 points of the returned polygon into WGS84(EPSG:4326)?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.x:

```
SpatialReference WGS1984 = SpatialReference.create(4326);
Polygon extent = (Polygon) GeometryEngine.project(
        mapView.getExtent(),
        mapView.getSpatialReference(),
        WGS1984);
for (int i = 0; i < extent.getPointCount(); i++) {
    Point corner = extent.getPoint(i);
    // Do something with that corner, e.g. print it...
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Here's a corner: " + corner.getX() + ", " + corner.getY(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

ArcGIS Runtime Quartz (Beta 3):

```
SpatialReference WGS1984 = SpatialReference.create(4326);
Envelope extent = (Envelope) GeometryEngine.project(
        mapView.getCurrentViewpoint(Viewpoint.Type.BOUNDING_GEOMETRY).getTargetGeometry(),
        WGS1984);
// Do something with the extent, e.g. print it...
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "Extent:\n(" + extent.getXMin() + ", " + extent.getYMin() + "),\n" +
                "(" +  extent.getXMax() + ", " + extent.getYMax() + ")",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Dear gary if i am trying to use `Cannot resolve method 'WGS1984()` is show it  cannot ressolve . Do you know why this happens ? Is there is any compile library needed means dependency ?

Comment: `WGS1984` is merely the variable name I chose for the return value of `SpatialReference.create(4326)`. It's not a method. Maybe you should create a new question and share your code in that question, because my code doesn't use `WGS1984` as a method.

Comment: Can you please have look at this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237103/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-how-to-get-the-lat-and-long-of-point

Comment: Please help me here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237257/how-to-calculate-new-point-coordinates-from-distance-and-angle-using-arcgis-runt